# .NET MAUI does not support Arabic language (RTL) on iOS devices

Tags: c#, ios, maui

.NET MAUI does not support Arabic language (RTL) on iOS devices ,

Images do not appear when the language is Arabic (RTL) when using ScrollView, Frame and border .

target framework .NET 7.0

Visual Studio for Mac 17.6.3(build 421)

Xcode (14.3.1)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         
             x:Class="TestRTL.MainPage">

    <ScrollView FlowDirection="RightToLeft" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <HorizontalStackLayout >
            <Frame HorizontalOptions="Start" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100"         BackgroundColor="Transparent" Padding="0" HasShadow="False" >
                <Image
                Source="dotnet_bot.png"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Cute dot net bot waving hi to you!"
                HeightRequest="80"
                WidthRequest="80"
                HorizontalOptions="Start" />

            </Frame>
            
             <Frame HorizontalOptions="Start" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Padding="0" HasShadow="False" >
                <Image
                Source="dotnet_bot.png"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Cute dot net bot waving hi to you!"
                HeightRequest="80"
                WidthRequest="80"
                HorizontalOptions="Start" />

            </Frame>
             <Frame HorizontalOptions="Start" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Padding="0" HasShadow="False" >
                <Image
                Source="dotnet_bot.png"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Cute dot net bot waving hi to you!"
                HeightRequest="80"
                WidthRequest="80"
                HorizontalOptions="Start" />

            </Frame>
             <Frame HorizontalOptions="Start" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Padding="0" HasShadow="False" >
                <Image
                Source="dotnet_bot.png"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Cute dot net bot waving hi to you!"
                HeightRequest="80"
                WidthRequest="80"
                HorizontalOptions="Start" />

            </Frame>
             <Frame HorizontalOptions="Start" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Padding="0" HasShadow="False" >
                <Image
                Source="dotnet_bot.png"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Cute dot net bot waving hi to you!"
                HeightRequest="80"
                WidthRequest="80"
                HorizontalOptions="Start" />

            </Frame>

        </HorizontalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vj6e3.png)

`<key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>`

`<array>`
`<string>en</string>`
`<string>ar</string>`
`</array>`

and
`FlowDirection="RightToLeft"`

Comment: known issue
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8556

Comment: Could you please [edit] post to clarify what kind of help/answer you are looking for? Note that SO is not the right place to simply report an issue (depending on a problem there are different paces to do so, for Maui in particular @Allanckw pointed to the right place where this issue is already reported).

Answer (score 0):

Accoring to Allanckw's comment, as an answer:

This is a known issue: [Flow direction is LeftToRight on iOS rtl language](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8556).

You can follow it to see if there are any updates.